# Sharing url to facebook from cross platform mobile app - Random Folder

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

I have a simple cordova app that has a facebook share button that shares a url to facebook. Facebook is putting in a random photo when the mobile facebook page opens. How do I replace this?

EDIT::: It has been suggested i use og:image to show an image. I did this, but it doesn't seem to be carrying through? Any thoughts? Is this due to using Cordova vs Java somehow?

[image]

Comment: You set the og:image tag on the url that you share

Comment: @WizKid SO this isn't working in the APP. Seems to be ok for websites, but in this cordova app... it isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work in APP? Which url are you trying to share?

Comment: Just doing a share like so: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.fs.usda.gov/alabama

Comment: So specify an og:image on http://www.fs.usda.gov/alabama

Comment: ah.. no. I it is on the page I am sharing from. Does it need to be on the page url being shared?

Comment: Yes it needs to be on the page being shared